# Открыть docx файл через doc4j

Tags: java

Необходимо открыть docx файл и узнать его заголовок. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не хватает рейтинга чтобы оставить простой коментрий, поэтому отвечу тут.
Вам стоит воспользоваться open source библиотекой [docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j). Так же не совсем понятно что Вы понимаете под заголовком, но, на всякий случай, вот Вам куча примеров на [github](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/tree/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples).